# Запрос из одной таблицы, с привязкой количества строк из другой таблицы

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird, interbase

Доброе время суток,
У меня есть таблица с группами опытов (и их результатами в таблице EXPERIMENTS).
 Опыты в группах могут быть как удачные, так и неудачные (в зависимости от выбранных при расчете коэффициентов), они обозначаются в поле RESULT, положительными и отрицательными значениями соответственно.
В EXPERIMENTS есть поле COEFFICIENT_ID, для привязки конкретных коэффициентов к конкретным опытам.

Есть вторая таблица с коэффициентами (COEFFICIENTS) для каждой группы, которые были использованы при расчете каждого опыта.

Перед проведением конкретного опыта группы, я вывожу на экран все возможные коэффициенты для данной группы. К таблице COEFFICIENTS привязан DataSet, отображающий набор коэффициентов для конкретной группы опытов.

```
select * from COEFFICIENT where GROUP = %s order by DATE_USE desc
```

Есть такой запрос:

```
select sum(case when a.SUM > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as POSITIVE,
       sum(case when a.SUM < 0 then 1 else 0 end) as NEGATIVE,
       c.ID, c.PRICE, c.STOP, c.TAKE, c.REMARK, c.IND_GROUP, c.DATE_USE
from COEFFICIENT c inner join EXPERIMENTS e on c.ID = e.COEFFICIENT_ID  
where c.IND_GROUP = 1
group by c.ID, c.PRICE, c.STOP, c.TAKE, c.REMARK, c.IND_GROUP, c.DATE_USE
order by c.DATE_USE desc
```

**Проблема**:
Дело в том, что в таблице COEFFICIENT, есть такие коэффициенты, которые привязаны к отдельным группам, но которые в опытах еще **НЕ** учавствовали. Так вот они в DataSet не отображаются, а их нужно отображать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `outer join`:

`inner join` -> `left join`